# Selenium xpath issue with GWT

Tags: firefox, gwt, selenium-rc

I have a button in the screen, whose text is 'Run Query'. I am trying to click on the same, and writing xpath, as the ids are getting generated dynamically.

```
selenium.click("//button[contains(text(), \"Run Query\"]");
```

which gives me error

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //button[contains(text(), "Run Query"]
```

also I tried with

```
selenium.click("//button[text() = \"Run Query\"]");
```

where I am getting :

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //button[text() = "Run Query"] not found
```

I am using 
Selenium RC: selenium-java-2.8.0.jar
Selenium server: selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar 
with firefox5.0

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of way you can handle this situation first you can try using the normalize-space function which is available in xapth

Example: `selenium.click("//button[normalize-space(text())=\"Run Query\"]")`

If this doesn't work try to look for the surround area of that button and use any stable icon around that button to pin point the button via that stable attribute/icon.

in xpath you can use Axises, `following, parent etc` use those function to get to the button rather than directly trying to use the button. Thats the best way to identify the Dynamic button.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for rerply, I ll try this. But could you think any reason why contains(), text() = \"Run Query\" are not working ?

Comment: I still get 
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //button[normalize-space(text())="Run Query"] not found  error with the solution you have given.

Comment: can you provide your dom structure without looking at the dom structure its really hard to answer selenium questions specially respect to xpath use. May be you can update the question with the dom structure.

Comment: How can I get the DOM structure ? can I get it through firebug ?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing text() with a . (dot).

```
selenium.click("//button[.=\"Run Query\"]")
```